# Customize Ubuntu syslinux CD Installation menu options

Tags: boot, customization, custom-distributions, syslinux, isolinux

I wonder to remove Function options from syslinux on Ubuntu CD installation iso.

I am customizing my own distro and I want to remove those options which are useless for my case.

I have tried changing .cfg files but doesn't work and I can't find proper setting to remove it. I succeed on changing background and some colors, but not customizing these options.

[image: Options to be removed from custom syslinux]

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords  is the way you are expected you to do this. Those 6 options are part of GRUB source code and not directly changeable from the ISO. You can though alter the GRUB config files on your ISO.

Comment: @Rinzwind, apparently, this is not related to Grub2, but syslinux

Comment: It looks so similar to grub2 what goes on when you press an f6 I assumed this is a frontend of grub ;-)  Can't find a way to disable it and I searched for a hour now :-*(